# Trigger a dialogflow intent using an event from external nodejs server

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

There is a scenario with google action and dialogflow if there is no intent match i want to start conversation between the **google action user and customer support person**.

For example, consider web browser chat application. In the browser we can create event listeners and from our nodejs web server we can send the messages by emitting an event. We can do this to and fro from client and server. I want to implement something similar to this.

Is this possible with google action and dialogflow?

Comment: yes, you can trigget specific intent using Dialogflow events.

Comment: It's getting triggered but, after triggering i want to send some message to google action user nikhil.

Comment: Can you share code that you did ?